# vmtoolsd doesn't end after logout

Tags: fedora, root, vmware, daemon, logout

There is a process 'vmtoolsd' `/usr/bin/vmtoolsd -n vmusr` left when a user logs out. I have to type root password to shutdown or restart because of this. How to prevent this from happening? And what package provide this command? I will remove the package to get rid of the problem as a last resort. I don't need to run virtual machines on my Fedora 19 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [existing bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/open-vm-tools/tracker/157/) that was discussed here on the [ArchLinux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=152097).

You can determine which package an executable is a member of with this command:

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/vmtoolsd
```

I believe this executable is part of the `open-vm-tools` package which is a package that's part of VMware. It's the opensource project that VMware spun off to contain the "VMware Tools".

Depending on which version of open-vm-tools you're using, your issue might be fixed by an upgrade. They're currently at [9.2.3 as of 04/2013](http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-vm-tools/files/open-vm-tools/stable-9.2.x/).

Comment: Already got rid of `open-vm-tools.x86_64 0:9.2.3-5.fc19`, thanks.